# Why do I have too many objects and how do I separate them? 2.8

Tags: modeling, object-mode

New to blender 2.8, I've noticed that when I create an object and then another object that they both seem to be in the same Object in the Collection so when I click to select one of them, all of them are selected.  Why does this happen and what should I be doing differently to have them be separate objects in the collection?[image: Want to delete the two cubes and keep the doorway,but all are the same Object]

Comment: possibly you have added the items in Edit Mode?

Comment: Thanks aliasguru!  I went into edit mode and I was able to delete them - but how would 'move' them to be their own objects?  Just learning Blender, thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try pressing P to separate by loose parts?

Comment: Add new objects in Object Mode instead